# Selecting Default Playlist Columns in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes

When you create a new playlist and select it in iTunes, it displays the following columns (renamed for clarity):

`#` `Song Title` `iCloud Status` `Length` `Artist` `Album` `Genre` `Rating` `Plays`

Is it possible to remove any of these defaults, or more generally pick a specific set of default columns to apply to new Playlists? I have no need for Genre, Rating, or Plays, and always immediately choose 'Auto Size All Columns' in a new playlist view after adding tracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New playlists use the current columns in the main music list. If you want to remove those columns, just remove them from the main browsing window (`Music` under `LIBRARY`). Then create a new playlist and you should see the new columns appear.

Comment: That can't be true, because I don't have Genre, Rating, and Plays in the main music list.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Lion to test on, this was just my iTunes v10.5.3 in Snow Leopard. Maybe the Lion version changes this?

Comment: Perhaps Lion, but I could also reasonably blame iTunes Match :).

Comment: Your answer is correct, but with one very very important caveat. I'm accepting your answer because it led to my discovery, but documenting it further in my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

After much agonizing, I discovered that claytron's answer above is correct, with the addition of only one very important detail.

The default All Music view's columns will be your default columns when in the same view mode of other items like playlists.

What do I mean by 'same view mode'?

[image: iTunes View Mode Switcher]

List View, Album List View, Grid (or Icon Mode), and Cover Flow.

The trick is that playlists start in the normal list view, where I use Album List view when browsing all my music. When I made this realization, I entered standard list view of all my music, fixed the columns I wanted displayed, and more importantly resized them, and then created a new playlist, and it looked identical to what I had just set up.

Out of curiosity, I went to an existing playlist and switched to Album List view, sure enough it looked identical to the setup I normally see on my all music view.

Comment: Or basically the list (and cover flow) and album list views have different default columns that are both copied from the Music group when creating a new playlist.

Comment: Correct, thank you. Since Cover Flow is just List view with a fancy picker up top.